# symfony2 doctrine2 not flushing new entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, flush

I have a form linked to a recipe object.
This recipe object has recipeCategories.

When modifying a recipe, updating any field would work great except for adding a new category.

My form:

```
$builder
    ->add('recipeCategories', 'entity',array(
            'multiple' => true,
            'class' => 'AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\RecipeCategory',
            'label' => 'Catégories',
            'required' => false,
            'attr'=>array(
                'data-toggle'=>"tooltip",
                'data-placement'=>"top",
                'title'=>"Indiquez les catégories dans lesquelles enregistrer la recette pour un recherche future plus facile",
            )))
```

Here is what I get :

```
    exit(var_dump($request->request));
```

The request does have the recipeCategories

```
    $recipeForm->handleRequest($request);
    exit(var_dump($recipeForm->getData()->getRecipeCategories()->toArray()));
```

The form does have the recipeCategories

```
    $formManager->getEntityManager()->persist($recipe);
    exit(var_dump($recipe->getRecipeCategories()->toArray()));
```

The recipe does have categories

```
    $formManager->getEntityManager()->flush($recipe);
    exit(var_dump($formManager->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions()));
```

With or without the flush, I get a null here

I am running symfony ~2.6.0 and doctrine ~1.3 with composer prefer-stable set to true.

Any idea of what I could do to make it work? Other fields are persisted correctly.
My entities are linked the following way:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe", inversedBy="recipeCategories")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="RecipeCategoryHasRecipe",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipeCategoryId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipeId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
 * )
 */
private $recipes;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I thought that defining by_reference => false in the form was only for collections but it's also the case here. I had to add the following code :

```
/**
 * Add recipeCategory
 *
 * @param RecipeCategory $recipeCategory
 *
 * @return Recipe
 */
public function addRecipeCategory(RecipeCategory $recipeCategory)
{
    $recipeCategory->addRecipe($this); //makes the difference
    $this->recipeCategories[] = $recipeCategory;

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: and the issue is related here https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/1566

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to set `cascade` parameter in your relation definition:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\FoodAnalytics\Recipe",     inversedBy="recipeCategories", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="RecipeCategoryHasRecipe",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipeCategoryId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="recipeId", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)}
 * )
 */
private $recipes;
```

Comment: the categories actually already exist, I am using the entity field type to allow for their selection. So unfortunately, cascading did not change it, no new record in the join table. Any idea of how I could debug this further?

Comment: @SébastienVassaux, you can try set `property_path` in form field manually, but it's just guessing.

Comment: 'property_path' => 'recipeCategories' does not work, would I need to change the value to something else?

Comment: @SébastienVassaux, it should be name of your property in entity, in this case: `recipes`.

Comment: well, it throws me an error with recipes, don't have access to it in the recipe entity. indeed, the form class is recipe and the field entity is RecipeCategories... So I guess this is not yet the solution.